# Find a group G that has subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for all natural numbers n $\geq$ 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was thinking of using the theorem: " If G is finite of order n, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ " But cannot find an appropriate group.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: The correct version of the theorem is "If G is cyclic AND finite of order n, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy example is the multiplicative group of the complex numbers. For each $n$ it has exactly one cyclic subgroup of order $n$, consisting of the solutions of $z^n-1=0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why for each n it has exactly one cyclic subgroup of order n?

Comment: I think I'm starting to see why this is true, my knowledge on complex analysis is a bit groggy as of now.

Comment: All the solutions of $z^n=1$ are powers of $\exp(2\pi i/n)$. @Wallace

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** true that every finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$.

However, you can take $G = \displaystyle \prod_{n \ge 2} \Bbb Z_n$, where $\prod$ means [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Infinite_direct_products).

Comment: I'm actually interested about your first statement. Could you provide me a counter example of a group with order n that is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups

Comment: @Wallace You know that there are non-abelian groups. They give enough counterexamples...

Comment: @KennyLau, thank you for providing me with this. It appears I have misread the theorem. It requires G to be cyclic! Thank you for this clarification. I will edit my original post

Comment: The order of the group $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb S = \mathbb R/1$, the set of all real numbers modulo $1$, i.e. the set of all sets of the form $[x] = \{x + n | n \in \mathbb Z\}$. Addition on $\mathbb S$ is defined by $[x]+[y] =[x+y]$. Then $\mathbb S$ is an abelian group with respect to addition. For any positive integer, $n$, the order of the group generated by $[\frac 1n]$ is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit silly, but you can use Cayley's theorem that states that every finite group is embedded in some symmetric group $S_n$, and then
$$
G = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} S_n
$$
will be a group that contains any finite group as a subgroup. This also is true for the symmetric group of the natural numbers $S(\mathbb N)$, since it contains all $S_n$ as subgroups.

Comment: I think you can take the subgroup of $G$ consisting of elements with finite support.

Comment: Yes, then we'd even be countable!